# f returning value of a variable inside of g in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to define a function f such that f(g,args,y) returns the value of the variable y before the return statement of g(args) in Python 3.x?

Example:

```
def g(x):
    y=x+1
    return(y+1)

assert f(g, 1, “y”) == 2
```

Bonus points if we are able to return the value of y before raising an exception if it happens, otherwise before the return statement of g.

Example:

```
def g(x):
    y=x+1
    z=1/x
    y+=z
    return(z)

assert f(g,0,”y”) == 1
assert f(g,1,”y”) == 3
```

Not sure about tags here.

Comment: Is this an abstract question asked out of curiosity, or do you think you actually need to do this? If it's the latter, it sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Take a look at the builtin [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). This won't let you extract variables from functions that have already executed, but it does enable the dynamic lookup of local variables by name.

Comment: @Brian that would be *major* code smell unless you were writing a debugger or something. This is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @kaya3 Pure curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but technically possible:

```
import inspect

def g(x):
    y=x+1
    return(y+1)

def f(g, arg, y):
    source = inspect.getsource(g)
    source = source.replace('def g', 'def n')
    source = source.replace('return', 'return %s\n    return' % y)
    print(source)
    exec('global n\n' + source)
    return n(arg)

assert f(g, 1, 'y') == 2
```

Better to set a breakpoint in `g` like so:

```
def g(x):
    y = x + 1
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return (y + 1)
```

Then when you run your assertion, the breakpoint will trigger and you can print y with the command `p y`.

Comment: This is a bit fragile; it won't be correct if there's a `return` statement that is more indented than four spaces, for example it will bump the "real" `return` statement outside of an `if` statement and make it unconditional. But the idea is good.

Comment: @kaya3 This is true, but not intended to be a robust solution, rather an illustration. I guess one could do some regex matching on the amount of whitespace preceding the return statement.

Comment: I think you would need to parse it with the `ast` module and change the `return` statements that way, otherwise there are too many tricky cases like `if something: return ...` or `do_something(); return ...` where the `return` isn't the start of the line it's on. My idea was to rewrite the bytecode to replace `LOAD_FAST (y)` and `STORE_FAST (y)` with appropriate reads/writes to somewhere else that `f` retains a reference to, but I don't think it's worth the effort to actually implement.